# How do I get the "Interests" of a facebook user uing Facebook Connect? (I'm using Django/python and pyFacebook middleware)

Tags: python, django, facebook

```
def index(request):
    fbdata = []
    if request.facebook.check_session(request):
        fbdata = request.facebook.users.getInfo(request.facebook.uid, ['name', 'pic'])
    print fbdata
```

This works!  I am able to get the user's picture and name.
However...I'd like to get the interests of that user. How can I do that?

By the way, I installed pyfacebook middleware on Django/python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "interests" in the fields you want to fetch, like this:

```
fbdata = request.facebook.users.getInfo(request.facebook.uid, 
                                        ['name', 'pic', 'interests'])
```